# MonoDevelop : "The number of bytes to be written is greater than the specified ContentLength"

Tags: c#, .net, exception, mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to develop the sms sending app but it gives an exception "The number of bytes to be written is greater than the specified ContentLength"
here's the code

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using WebKit;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{   
    byte[] dataout; //global variables
    Stream stream = null;
    int length;
    public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {

        Build ();
        requestweb ();

        this.DeleteEvent += OnDeleteEvent;

    }
    private void requestweb() //the post method
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (s,ce,ca,p) => true;
        string index = entryIndex.Text;
        string number = entryNumber.Text;
        string sms = textviewSMS.Buffer.Text;
        string captcha = entryCaptcha.Text;
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string postData = "send=1&smstext=" + sms + "&smstoprefix=" + index + "&smsto=" + number + "&dirtysmstext=" + sms
            + "&translit=on&confirm_key=1&confirmcode=" + captcha + "&x=0&y=0";

        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes (postData);
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://mobile.beeline.ge/ge/main/sms/send.wbp");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataout = data;
        length = data.Length;



    }
    private void addWebView() //load captcha url
    {
        WebView web = new WebView ();
        web.Open ("https://mobile.beeline.ge/ge/main/sms/mamimg.aspx");

        web.SetSizeRequest(60,19);
        captchaImage.Add (web);
        captchaImage.ShowAll ();
    }

    protected void OnButtonSendClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendSMS ();
    }




    private void SendSMS()
    {
        stream.Write(dataout, 0, length);
        stream.Close();
    }
    void OnDeleteEvent(object o, DeleteEventArgs args){
        Application.Quit();
        args.RetVal = true; //this is necessary to stop an error on close.
    }

    protected void OnButton1Clicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addWebView (); //this loads captcha
    }
}
```

The reason i split the send function into to methods is that captcha must be loaded after the request and before sending.
Here's the terminal output:

```
alex@alex-PC:~$ mono /home/alex/C#/BeeSMS/BeeSMS/bin/Release/BeeSMS.exe
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:000] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:000] Using Gtk2 toolkit
No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:013] Warning(optionsfile.cc:47): Load: Could not open file, err=2
[000:013] No bp log location saved, using default.
[000:013] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
[000:013] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
[000:013] Using Gtk2 toolkit
[000:000] Warning(optionsfile.cc:47): Load: Could not open file, err=2
[000:000] No bp log location saved, using default.
java version "1.7.0_15"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.7) (7u15-2.3.7-0ubuntu1~12.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
Marshaling clicked signal
Exception in Gtk# callback delegate
  Note: Applications can use GLib.ExceptionManager.UnhandledException to handle the exception.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: The number of bytes to be written is greater than the specified ContentLength.
  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.CheckWriteOverflow (Int64 contentLength, Int64 totalWritten, Int64 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.BeginWrite (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, System.AsyncCallback cb, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MainWindow.SendSMS () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MainWindow.OnButtonSendClicked (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.Signal.ClosureInvokedCB (System.Object o, GLib.ClosureInvokedArgs args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.SignalClosure.Invoke (GLib.ClosureInvokedArgs args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at GLib.SignalClosure.MarshalCallback (IntPtr raw_closure, IntPtr return_val, UInt32 n_param_vals, IntPtr param_values, IntPtr invocation_hint, IntPtr marshal_data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
   at GLib.ExceptionManager.RaiseUnhandledException(System.Exception e, Boolean is_terminal)
   at GLib.SignalClosure.MarshalCallback(IntPtr raw_closure, IntPtr return_val, UInt32 n_param_vals, IntPtr param_values, IntPtr invocation_hint, IntPtr marshal_data)
   at Gtk.Application.gtk_main()
   at Gtk.Application.Run()
   at BeeSMS.MainClass.Main(System.String[] args)
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You just get the stream `request.GetRequestStream()`, but write nothing to it.

try:

```
var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(data,0,data.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

there's another method for stream write

```
private void SendSMS()
{
    stream.Write(dataout, 0, length);
    stream.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to **Web.config** file by adding this section of code in **System.webServer** section.

```
<security> 
<requestFiltering> 
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="3000000000" /> 
</requestFiltering> 
</security>
```